# Require class to implement method with params based on generics

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

I have a ClassDecorator that takes an unspecified number of Constructor params `(<T>: { new (...args: any[]) => T })` and based on that I want that class to require to implement a method with parameters that mirrors the types of those supplied constructors.

My decorator:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ComponentArray = Array<Constructor<unknown>>;

export interface TSystem<TComps extends ComponentArray> {
  handle: (...comps: TComps) => void;
}


export function System<TComps extends ComponentArray>(...comps: TComps) {
  return (ctor: Constructor<Required<TSystem<TComps>>>) => {
     // add metadata etc...
  };
}
```

Example:

```
class RandomComponent {
  test1: string;
  // implementation ...
}

class RandomComponent2 {
  test2: string;
  // implementation ...
}

@System(RandomComponent, RandomComponent2 /* etc ... */)
class TestSystem {
  handle(r1: RandomComponent, r2: RandomComponent2 /* etc... */) {
    // handle components ...
  }
}
```

I hoped this would work however the compiler gives me this error:

```
Type '(comp: RandomComponent) => void' is not assignable 
to type '(comps_0: typeof RandomComponent) => void'
```

Is there a way I can remove the typeof from the TSystem interface or maybe accomplish this in a different way? I want to access an instance of the Class not the type of it. Or is this just a limitation of the TypeScript type system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works for me on 3.5.1 i'll post it here, can you update your question with where the error is and i'll update my answer. What you're describing definitely `is` possible with Typescript.

https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAKFCRYcALZhEEBMACCqVExBkoGrSDzoEAawRwqCIlMkQAHktTAoAS1URUAMyaZoBAMogKBDyhPCKSFD2wCoAJpHhSpSq+tokAN6SUFAAFjyxADYQXAyMmApgnFAEiUgipCQAbnAusVIAvpJd9o7OnsbYLohQgcGhNRWR0XEJFcopmmml9OURXBMRIpnZqBDA6KgIdNi4XPDIaFg4+ABKEACO6C67sYSjMeO1RN-1GVnZ2QA9IDuLFYlB5HsmLEmMAmFFgJhGPR-u0Ol1MAUmEhIjd8gpEvNnNsoMC5Ioia5FEVIapYUMEJJOpIAALvEK0PEIWIEubJYBCSSY7GRAgQFDs+RQEl5blFWirMBcLk8+SE-lbUkgqi4ExIf5AkHIqKxFzORWoplAA

EDIT:
Change this line

```
  handle(comp: typeof RandomComponent)
```

I'm pretty sure that should do it to what you want let me know.

EDIT2: I think this is what you want.

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ComponentArray = Array<Constructor<unknown>>;

export interface TSystem<TComps extends ComponentArray> {
  handle: (...comps: ConvertInstanceTypes<TComps>) => void;
}

type ConvertInstanceTypes<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Constructor<any> ? InstanceType<T[K]> : never;
}


export function System<TComps extends ComponentArray>(...comps: TComps) {
  return (ctor: Constructor<Required<TSystem<TComps>>>) => {
     // add metadata etc...
  };
}

class RandomComponent {
  test1: string = "test1";
  // implementation ...
}

class RandomComponent2 {
  test2: string = "test2";
  // implementation ...
}


@System(RandomComponent, RandomComponent2)
class TestSystem {
  handle(r1: InstanceType<typeof RandomComponent>, r2: InstanceType<typeof RandomComponent2>) {
    // handle components ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It will work if the component class is empty, if u add a property you will get the error. I updated my question

Comment: No what I'm trying to do is to access an instance of the component inside the `handle()` method. Eg. `sys.handle(new RandomComponent());` would not work if the parameter is a typeof

Comment: Iv'e added another edit i'm pretty sure that's what you want; added a tuple mapped type which loops every class to its instance type.

Comment: Thanks! `ConvertInstanceTypes` was the missing link, it all works perfectly! Didn't know you could convert an array like that.

Comment: You can only convert a tuple like that, but rest parameters can inferred as a tuple instead of an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195751/discussion-between-frans-bstrom-and-shanon-jackson).